# Gitlist with different repository and different ldap

Tags: git, ldap, gitlist

I have migrated from Svn to Git. Everything works fine but I'd like to config Apache in order to use url to map different repositories with different ldap authorization rules. Ex:

```
http://domaniserver/repo1 -> popoup for ldap1 -> fill the blanks -> open view  
http://domaniserver/repo2 -> popoup for ldap2 -> fill the blanks -> open view
```

I decide to use GitList as web interface (clean and very simple to use ) but I manged to do that behavior with this config in httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/gitlist
Alias /repo1 /var/www/gitlist/repo1
<directory /var/www/gitlist/repo1>
AuthName "XXX for Repo1"
...
<directory>

Alias /repo1 /var/www/gitlist/repo1
 <directory /var/www/gitlist/repo2>
AuthName "yyy for Repo2"
...
<directory>
```

In this way I copied gitlist project both in /var/www/gitlist/repo1  and in /var/www/gitlist/repo2 and setup config.ini setting for both repositories location.

This solution force to have as many copies of gitlist as repositories with different ldap,   but i don't think it's the right way to do it.

I'd like to have just one copy of gitlist and manage  all repositories and related ldap with it, do you any advice to do that?

thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is ok but I had to remove alias :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/gitlist

<directory /var/www/gitlist/repo1>
AuthName "XXX for Repo1"
...
<directory>


<directory /var/www/gitlist/repo2>
AuthName "yyy for Repo2"
...
<directory>
```

it's enough!